# Alternatives to Tidy.NET?

Tags: .net, html

I need to clean-up and validate some html markup in various places. I'm currently using Tidy.NET for this purpose, but this tool seems to have been abandoned for years — it has some bugs and does not support HTML 5 tags (f.e. `<canvas />`).

So, the question is: what are the alternatives, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) should be useful here. It is still being maintained, but I am unsure whether it supports HTML 5 tags or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could fork Tidy.Net on Github and add the features you want:

https://github.com/WordFly/TidyNet